# Python CGI server extract request header

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, cgi

I am trying to run a python CGI server. The cgi-bin folder in server has the test.cgi file. I am sending a curl request to this server and am expecting the request header to be printed in the CGI.
I saw several stackoverflow pages suggesting using os.environ variables to get the header information. However, I don't get the request headers from environ values.

I am running a python CGI server using the following code:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

server = HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPRequestHandler 
server_address("", 8080)
handler.cgi_directories = ["/cgi-bin"]

httpd = server(server_address, handler)
httpd.serve_forever
```

I have a test.cgi script in cgi-bin folder. The test.cgi has the following code

```
import os
import cgi
print "content type: text/html"
for headername, headervalue in os.environ.iteritems():
  print "<p> {0} = {1} </p>".format(headername,headervalue) <--- This prints Content-length header but not someheader
```

sample curl request
curl -i -X GET "http:127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/test.cgi" -H "someheader : value"

Comment: You have to spell the header name correctly (incl. hyphen) and there are two linebreaks needed after the headers.

Comment: @KlausD. I am not sure whether I understood your comment. The for loop would print all the available environment variable. I don't see my header(someheader) in that list

Comment: It is `Content-Type:`.